# I don't know the ID of the input I want to select

Tags: jquery

I have multiple buttons in a div. These buttons are within a Form which is also dynamically named. They are of type=submit. They all have a unique ID which I cannot know the name of beforehand.

They're all in a div:

```
#caseview
```

How do I get the ID of the button that was clicked and store in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#caseview input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: **bonus demo** http://jsfiddle.net/63Yk6/

`:)`

```
$('#caseview > input[type=submit]').click(function(){


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this HTML:

```
   <div id="caseview">
    <input type="submit" value ="button1"  id ="button1"/>
    <input type="submit" value ="button2"  id ="button2" />
</div>
```

Use this JS:

```
   $("#caseview").find('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    alert( $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

And finally here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62F66/)